# How to get a test's run execution time from JUnit's TestResult?

Tags: java, junit

I am using `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` class to run test from inside my java application. I have added my custom listener implementing `org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener` for reporting purpose. 
Currently from listener I am getting total time of all the tests by calling `getRunTime()` method of `org.junit.runner.Result` class. I want to get the (individual) method execution time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your listener can get the current time when `testStarted()` is called and then again get the current time when `testFinished()` is called. the time difference would be the amount of time the test took to run.

Comment: I have calculated time manually but there isn't any listener method to get the time taken by the test.

Comment: According to the javadoc http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html `testStarted()` is called when each `@Test` is about to be called and `testFinished()` is called when each `@Test` has finished whether it passed or failed.